# Table inside of a div will not center and is slightly off. How can I get a table perfectly centered using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have spent considerable time researching this and could not find a working solution from the other answers presented here. With that said, I apologize if this seems to be a duplicate; none of the researched solutions worked and I am completely baffled as to why.

The following is the portion of code which is slightly off-center. Oddly, I have the same set-up on a different page - the only difference being one link in the table says "Resume" instead of "Main" - and that is centered perfectly.

EDIT: Sorry, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xu586r1d/) is the fiddle with the changes suggested by blearn and UndoingTech.

```
<body class="center style">
    <div class="center style">          
        <object data="Resume.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px"> 
        </object>       
    <div style="center" align="center">
    <a href="Resume.pdf" style="color:navy">Download Resume</a>
    </div>
    <div style="width:50%;margin:0 auto; justify-content:center" align="center">
        <table class="center">
        <tr style="color:orangered;text-align:center"   class="linkoutline">
            <td><a href="index.html"
            class="link">Main</a></td>
            <td><a href="projects.html"
            class="link">Projects</a></td>
            <td><a href="https://github.com/mygithub"
            class="link">
                GitHub</a></td>
            <td><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mylinkedin"
            class="link">
                LinkedIn</a></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the css formatting:

```
html, body
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

body.center
{
    margin-left:15%;
    margin-right:15%;
}

body.style
{
     font-family:Helvetica;
     font-size:12pt;
     background-color:#FFAB91;
}

div.center
{
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right:1%;
    padding-left:1%;
    padding-right:1%;
}

div.style
{
    background-color:white;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100vh;
}

p.center
{
    /*
    Should be slightly narrower than the div
    */
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:5%;
}

td
{
    /*
    Make cell spacing with a transparent horizontal border
    */
    border-left: solid 15px transparent;
    border-right: solid 15px transparent;
}

td.vertpadding
{
    /*
    Some space between table cells
    */
    border-bottom: solid 40px transparent;
}

table.center
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:20px;
}

ol, ul
{
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    padding-left:15;
    padding-right:15;
}

h4.small
{
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:5;
    color:steelblue;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:12pt;
}

a
{
    color:orangered;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:visited
{
    color:firebrick;
}

a:hover, a:active
{
    /*
    Increase font upon mouseover
    */
    font-size:125%;
}
```

Many solutions recommended doing things such as set the parent container's text-align to center; that did not work. Reducing the child div width and setting margin to 0 auto only worked on the other page, but not this one. The table is only off by about a half an inch. If I set the left margin to something like 30%, it works, but I would like to have the margin be dynamically determined by the dimensions of the parent div if at all possible.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/  add your code here ;)

Comment: Haha, that is extremely useful! I was clunking around in the text box for sure. Ok, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xu586r1d/) it is with the changes suggested by blearn and Undoing Tech.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can center the table keeping it absolutely positioned using the `transform` trick as shown below so that `bottom:20px;` works as expected

```
table.center {
  position: absolute;
  left:50%; /*add this */
  bottom: 20px;
  transform: translate(-50%); /* and this */
  border: 5px solid red;
  /*margin: auto; no longer needed*/
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body.center {
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
}
body.style {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 12pt;
  background-color: #FFAB91;
}
div.center {
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
}
div.style {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}
p.center {
  /*
    Should be slightly narrower than the div
    */
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
td {
  /*
    Make cell spacing with a transparent horizontal border
    */
  border-left: solid 15px transparent;
  border-right: solid 15px transparent;
}
td.vertpadding {
  /*
    Some space between table cells
    */
  border-bottom: solid 40px transparent;
}
#edited {
  border: 5px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
table.center {
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  bottom: 20px;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  border: 5px solid red;
  /*margin: auto;*/
}
ol,
ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 15;
  padding-right: 15;
}
h4.small {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5;
  color: steelblue;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
a {
  color: orangered;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: firebrick;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
  /*
    Increase font upon mouseover
    */
  font-size: 125%;
}
```

```html
<body class="center style">
  <div class="center style">
    <object data="Resume.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px">
    </object>
    <div style="center" align="center">
      <a href="Resume.pdf" style="color:navy">Download Resume</a>
    </div>
    <div id="edited">
      <table class="center">
        <tr style="color:orangered;text-align:center" class="linkoutline">
          <td><a href="index.html" class="link">Main</a>
          </td>
          <td><a href="projects.html" class="link">Projects</a>
          </td>
          <td><a href="https://github.com/mygithub" class="link">
                GitHub</a>
          </td>
          <td><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mylinkedin" class="link">
                LinkedIn</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me with both the centering and also keeping the table planted at the bottom of the page. I will educate myself about using transform.

Comment: @fire_bad `left: 50%` puts the left border of the table at center of elements container (here 50% is the 50% of parent) , now the table will be pushed towards right. `transform:translate()` lets us reposition an element based on itself, so we pull half of the table backwards (`-50%`, here 50% is the 50% of the size of table itself) from the current position (center of the parent) using `translate`, now it's centered.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position:absolute` from

```
table.center
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:20px;
}
```

This will make the table fall within its containing div's positioning. Right now, it is statically placing it at an exact location on the html page.

Comment: That did help with the centering issue! I just need to figure out how to make the table stay 20px above the bottom of the page...

Answer (score 1):

I have made a few edits to your code in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/undoingtech/44ckgukL/).  Here is a summary of what I did:

Like bleam said, I took out the position code.  I added `text-align: center` to the parent div and `margin:auto` to the table.

```
#edited {
  border: 5px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  /* Added after EDIT */
  position: absolute:
  bottom: 20px;
}

table.center {
  /*position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;*/
  border: 5px solid blue;
  margin: auto;
}
```

I also changed this line `<div style="width:50%;margin:0 auto; justify-content:center" align="center">` to this `<div id="edited">`.  The borders are not needed.  They are only there so you can see the boundaries.

**EDIT:** I have added the position code to the `#edited` part.  That might work for you.

Comment: Oh wow that was incredibly detailed, thank you! Also, I didn't even know about that tool, fiddle. Your answer and blearn's both helped me. My only issue is on the other pages, the link table is really high up. Would there happen to be a non-absolute positioning where I could always have that table 20px above wherever the bottom is? Thank you again!

Comment: Sorry I just saw your edit. I went ahead and tried it, but I couldn't get it to work quite like I needed it to. Thank you for your help. I'm going to work on improving my knowledge of positioning. :)